# Offline server-based to register attendees

Tags: windows, database, offline

So we have a voluntary activity that we currently track user engagement and participation on our events on paper, but we want to make this process digital.

The users currently are sorted in two different categories:

- first time participants
- recurring ones.

On their first time, we store some amount of personal information that the attendees gives to us, such as e-mail, phone, address and comments they have on why they are coming there, and some other multiple choice questions regarding our activity.

For recurring people we have some follow-up questions to see if the attendee followed our guidelines, if they made any improvements and so on.

Only our staff access this system, not the attendees.

The tricky part is that we need this to be an **offline** system, and somehow it needs to track user participation through time. Also, the main goal is to allow us to send future e-mail, SMS, WhatsApp or some other form of communication with the attendees in the future, since now we manully call one by one (over 300 manual SMS per day).

I thought of using an offline **Mautic** installation on-site and then somehow transfering the database to our online server, so we can send e-mails, but this sounds too much hassle.

Do you have any suggestions on what we could use?

Comment: https://www.mautic.org/ ?     Do you have anyone who could could some of the solution, or do you want something completely of the shelf?  What about Drupal? An Sqlite database is only a single file and easy to copy, so maybe something that supports Sqlite as a back-end?

Comment: I was more looking for something that was already mostly done, and I could change what questions/fields I wanted to ask, and then just export the data.

Comment: I have one person who could do some of the solution if it's not fully done. I thought of using some JS framework on top of some simple controler.